# How to use ECMA6 features in Meteor 1.2 in apps written in older Meteor versions

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6

I just upgraded to Meteor 1.2 and everything works fine except that I am trying to use the new features in 1.2 especially the ECMA6 specs in a Meteor project written in Meteor 1.1 but I am getting error messages like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode` when I try to create a `class` or use other ES6 features.

I quickly tried to create a new app in Meteor 1.2 with ES6 features and that worked fine.

Do I need to change something in the old project to turn on ES6?

Comment: try `meter update` (in the console)

Answer (score 3):

According to the official Meteor 1.2 [announcement](http://info.meteor.com/blog/announcing-meteor-1.2) :

> Want to use ES2015 in an existing app?  Just add the new `ecmascript` package.

So a `meteor add ecmascript` should do the trick. `api.use` it for packages.
You can check this by running `meteor list` on new applications created with `meteor create`.

---

<sub>*Since this is a direct extraction from the official website, I do not want any reputation out of it, hence the community wiki.*</sub>

Comment: `meteor add ecmascript` did the trick. I checked in .meteor/versions earlier that `ecmascript ` was/became a package used in the old app when I upgraded to Meteor 1.2, but it seems like you have to add it manually one more time.